# Banach space of continuously differentiable function on $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity, banach-spaces, frechet-derivative

I am a bit confused how the Banach space of continuously differentiable functions on $\Omega \subset R^n$ (possible unbounded), $n\geq 2$ is defined.

Let us assume that $n=2$ and $\Omega=R^2.$ Is it too much to demand that $f(x,y)$ is continuous and its partial derivatives are continuous functions on $\Omega$, with

$$
\| f\| =\sup \limits_{(x,y)\in \Omega} \left(|f(x,y)|+ |\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)|+|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)|\right)
$$

Would appreciate some help here...
Thank you!

Comment: Just thinking that if $f$ is differentiable its Frechet derivative is given as

$$
(D_{(a,b)} f)(x,y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (a,b) x +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (a,b) y.
$$

Thus, $D_{(a,b)} f$ is continuous if partial derivatives are uniformly bounded on $\Omega$. So it seems that asking for them being bounded and continuous is too much... but perhaps I am missing something. 

Just wonder what is the classical definition, but could not find it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the classic definition. See for example [Banach Spaces III: Banach Spaces of Continuous Functions](https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/func-an-2007-2008/bs-3.pdf). A norm is by definition real-valued, so if $\|\cdot\| = \sup(\cdots) = \infty$, it is not a norm.

Comment: mm... there is no problem with the definition of the norm, but rather with what has to  be demanded from f(x,y) that $C_b^1(\Omega)$ is a Banach space.

Comment: @JaneEyre, the uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous. Convergence in this norm implies uniform convergence of function and partial derivatives.

Comment: yes... I agree. 
So $C^1_b(\Omega),$ $\Omega \subset R^2$  is the space of continuous functions  $f(x,y)$ with the Jacobian $J_f: \Omega \to L(\Omega, R)$ being the continuous map, which is equivalent of saying that $f(x,y)$ is a continuous function with continuous partial derivatives!

Thank you!